# Use custom spacing after using newcolumntype with siunitx

Tags: tables, siunitx

I can't seem to find a way to use stuff like `@{blah blah}` around custom column types that involve `siunitx`'s `S` column type with `[…]` parameters. (The problem seems to occur with `>{}` too but that's not what I need right now.)
Here is an example which should make all this clearer. The five first tabulars work just fine, while the sixth causes a “Illegal pream-token” error, even though this last tabular seemed to me to be the obvious followup to the previous ones…

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\stuff}{\hspace{2\tabcolsep}}

\begin{tabular}{c @{\stuff} c}
    1 & 1 \\
\end{tabular}

\newcolumntype{C}{c}
\begin{tabular}{C @{\stuff} C}
    2 & 2 \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{S @{\stuff} S}
    3 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}

\newcolumntype{t}{S}
\begin{tabular}{t @{\stuff} t}
    4 & 4 \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{S[table-format = 1] @{\stuff} S[table-format = 1]}
    5 & 5 \\
\end{tabular}

\newcolumntype{T}{{S[table-format = 1]}}
\begin{tabular}{T @{\stuff} T}
    6 & 6 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Therefore, the combination of `S[…]`, `\newcolumntype` and `@{…}` seems to be the source of the problem. I guess I'm missing something stupid here… Hope you will be able to help. Thanks!

By the way, in my *real* document, the custom column type is this one:

```
\newcolumntype{e}[3]{%
    {S[
        table-format        = #1.#2e-#3,
        exponent-base       = e,
        exponent-product    = {\,}
    ]}%
}
```

(The additional braces pair around `S[…]` seem to be necessary because `\newcolumntype` seems to parse stuff in a weird way.)

Until I find a better solution, I guess I'll use a `\sisetup` at the beginning of my `table` environment or something… Not very pretty. o( +_+ )o

**Edit:** Using the provided solution, my real column type now looks like this:

```
\newcolumntype{e}[3]{%
    S[{
        table-format        = #1.#2e-#3,
        exponent-base       = e,
        exponent-product    = {\,}
    }]%
}
```

and can be used like this: `\begin{tabular}{e121 @{\hspace{2\tabcolsep}} e121}`, etc.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: With your example code, just one pair of braces works fine: `\newcolumntype{T}{S[table-format = 1]}`.

Comment: The additional braces just stop the column type being recognised at all, if you get errors in a table without them you should ask about _that_.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle @Bernard Thanks for your answers. However, I tend to get a “TeX capacity exceeded” error when I remove them, but it's true that it actually does not occur in the example… Sorry about that. … Actually, `\newcolumntype{e}{S[table-format = 1]}` does not work because it seems that the “e” in “table-format” gets recursively replaced: the error message shows something like `S[tablS[tablS[tablS[tablS[tablS[tablS[tablS[tablS[tablS[tabl`. In other words, it only works if the parameters of `S` do not contain the chosen column name. I need to make that work.

Comment: If you  want to ask about an error message ask a new question about that error, together with an example that produces the error. Just using more invalid syntax such as spurious braces to make an error message go is not likely to help in the long term.

Comment: although `\newcolumntype{e}{S[{table-format = 1}]} ` probably works.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was merely pointing out the fact that the initial solution was not very generic and that it might have caused issues to those with other parameters. But your new version with the braces *inside* the brackets seems to work with any column name (I wonder why it works, though). Nice! Thanks, and my apologies; I tried to identify the problem as precisely as I could, but I guess that still wasn't enough…

Comment: @AliceM. it is a general feature of tex argument parsing that if the argument consists of a single `{}` group then one level of `{}` is removed (so I just assumed that would work, although I hadn't tested it as your example didn't need that)

Comment: @AliceM. it's not really an "initial solution" and a later one, it is two solutions for two completely different problems. The error message in the example document posted is just caused by the extra braces, you would get a similar error from `{c}` instead of `c` the second issue of the `e` in `table-format` expanding you only mentioned in comments later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\newcolumntype{T}{S[table-format = 1]}
```

not

```
\newcolumntype{T}{{S[table-format = 1]}}
```

or for letters that appear in the argument, guard the argument with inner `{}`

```
\newcolumntype{e}{S[{table-format = 1}]}
```

Comment: Maybe you should update your answer with the `\newcolumntype{e}{S[{table-format = 1}]}` version which allows any column name and `S` parameters, in case someone needs it. It seems way more robust to me.

Comment: @AliceM. done..